# Text On top of darkened transparent background

Tags: css, html

So earlier, I was trying to figure out how to darken an image with transparency using CSS but when I figured that out, the new question came was how would I place text over that? This is what i have so far... http://jsfiddle.net/PXU6j/3/

```
 <h1> Any Help Will Be  appreciated </h1>
```

Comment: By text do you mean that logo or new text? And what are you struggling with?

Comment: Post your code in your question and don't try to sidestep the SO rule of doing so when linking to jsFiddle.net.

Comment: well like just posting text in general, on top of the transparency.

Comment: @user3430532 Create span with some text e.g. `<span>This is some text.</span>` and use `span { position: absolute; display: block; top: 100px; left: 100px; z-index: 9999; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Examples) to draw content (such as text) over other content.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j8592/27/

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container img {float: left;}
.foo-background {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.foo-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```